# Restoring back up file is failed (on device xx.bak is incorrectely formed and cannot be read

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, database-restore

I am using a SQL server 2016 and trying to restore my bakup file with new database. But Its showing the below message "on device xx.bak  is incorrectely formed and cannot be read".
This is the Restore statement that I am using : 
      RESTORE DATABASE TESTDB FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DEMO_clone.bak'  WITH  FILE = 38,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backup path suggests you are trying to restore SQL Server 2016 database backup. You cannot restore a backup made from a later SQL Server version to an earlier version.

Comment: OMG ! I edited my Question. Its 2016 sorry ! .Its not restoring in 2016 , why ?

Comment: @SreejeshBabu, execute [`RESTORE HEADERONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql) to verify the backup version.

Comment: Yea.. How to use this can you send me the complete script forf restore headeronly ?

Comment: How to give a destination DB ?

Comment: `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DEMO_clone.bak'`. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql). Note the `SoftwareVersionMajor` in the result.